# Microsoft bot builder cards imback method doesnt display text on Slack

Tags: node.js, botframework, slack

I have a bot using Microsoft bot builder node.js sdk. I started to add hero cards to the conversation and it is working fine except that even if I use imBack type button, slack doesn't display the value of the button. However, in other channels like Skype, when user presses 'OK' say, 'OK' is also written into the chat screen as a user message, as expected
I want to know how I can have the same with Slack

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the differences in the implementation between Skype (1st party partner channel) and Slack (3rd party channel), what you are asking for is not currently available as a feature.

Slack channel does not support `imBack` style messages. If you send an `imBack` on Slack, it is converted to `postBack` style message (message text is hidden from user).

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer!