# Slack button not send response when using bot frame work

Tags: c#, botframework, slack

When the bot sends a post back reply to the slack by button click event. The slack did not reply, Some documentation say slack accept post back event [Microsoft bot builder cards imback method doesnt display text on Slack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45761711/microsoft-bot-builder-cards-imback-method-doesnt-display-text-on-slack) but I cant find how. I’m using bot frame work connector not adaptor.

```
public static HeroCard GetHeroCard(List<string> answerlist)
    {
        List<CardAction> cardButtons = new List<CardAction>();
        for (int i = 0; i <= answerlist.Count-1; i++) 
        {
            var reply = i + 1;
            //CardAction plButton = new CardAction(ActionTypes.ImBack)
            CardAction plButton = new CardAction()
            {
                Value = reply.ToString(),
                Type = ActionTypes.PostBack,
                Title = answerlist[i]
            };
            cardButtons.Add(plButton);
        }
        var heroCard = new HeroCard
        {
            Title = "",
            Subtitle = "",
            Text = "",
            Buttons = cardButtons,
        };
        return heroCard;
    }
```

[![buttons image][1]][1]

Answer (score 1):

I checked [MS Documents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-channel-connect-slack?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=abs) and found I missed one setting.

Add and Configure Interactive Messages (optional).
It solved the problem perfectly.